# InstrumentationTestRunner: What does android:functionalTest achieve?

Tags: android, testing, instrumentation

I am wondering what [InstrumentationInfo#functionalTest](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/InstrumentationInfo.html#functionalTest) is supposed to achieve. Does it have any impact on how the application environment is started?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I asked this question on the Android issue tracker (unfortunately I can't find the ticket anymore), and a Google rep answered and said: this attribute is not implemented, reserved for future use, and hence, does nothing at the moment.

Comment: Wonder if this is still the case?